# Sql Server Managment Studio Missing Table Right Click Menu Options

Tags: ssms

After an install at a client site of SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 R2, when I connect to an Azure database, expand the tree to show the tables, the right click menu is missing the following items: Select top 1000 Rows, Edit top 200 Rows, and Design. The version of SSMS is the same as the one installed on my dev machine which has these options. Searched high and low and no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is confirmation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/nl-nl/ssdsgetstarted/thread/9fd1a3d6-b094-4e15-b9a6-b2c3e7aa2198) that you're not crazy—this basic feature is missing from SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 R2.